# PHP different session ID's on the same domain

Tags: php, session, sessionid

I created a simple session class that handles sessions.
However I am encountering big problems with the session_id.

*small note: it happens to go just well for a couple of weeks. and all of a sudden it stops working*

What's the case :

**http://domain1.com/framework/start/**

Has the following Session ID: **svplf2tln1j05n75jbokcmhfo3**

**http://domain1.com/framework/login/**

Has the following Session ID: **njlqg0jomo00r560bp6k0pje55**

This is strange.

But important to know my settings:

```
            ///######## IF A SESSION COOKIE SHOULD BE SET
        if(self::$setsessioncookie === true){
            ///######## SETTINGS ARRAY
            $SessionSettings = array(
                                        'session.cookie_lifetime'       =>          self::$limit,           /// **** LIFETIME OF THE SESSION COOKIE (in seconds)
                                        ///'session.cookie_path'           =>          self::$path,         /// **** THE DOMAIN FOR WHERE THE COOKIE WILL WORK. (single /  for all paths on the domain.)
                                        'session.cookie_domain'         =>          self::$domain,          /// **** DEFINE THE DOMAIN NAME
                                        'session.cookie_secure'         =>          self::$secure,          /// **** ONLY BY SECURE CONNECTIONS
                                        'session.cookie_httponly'       =>          self::$httponly         /// **** INDICATE THAT THE SESSION COOKIE IS AVAILABLE THROUGH HTTP PROTOCOLS ONLY (not by Javascript)
                                    );
            ///########==================================================
            ///######## SET THE SESSION COOKIE PARAMETERS
            ///########==================================================
            ///######## RUN THROUGH ALL SETTINGS
            foreach($SessionSettings as $Option => $Setting){
                ///######## IF THE OPTION IS NOT EMPTY
                if($Setting !== NULL){
                    ///######## SET THE SETTING
                    ini_set($Option, $Setting);
                }
            }
```

As you see I commented out :

```
'session.cookie_path'           =>          self::$path
```

So it should not be limited to one path only.
But the problem still occurs.

Before doing this I set a session cookie:

```
///########==================================================
///######## STORING THE SESSION ID IN A COOKIE
///########==================================================
setcookie(
            self::$SessionName,             /// **** SET THE COOKIE NAME
            session_id(),                   /// **** SET THE COOKIE CONTENTS
            (time() + self::$limit)         /// **** MAX DURATION OF THE COOKIE LIFETIME
        );
///########==================================================
```

Or should I do this before setting the **ini_set**??

**Small update:**
I have the FireFox webdeveloper extension installed and when I click: "Delete path cookies" the system logs out and allows me to login properly.

This could indicate that the path has been set? But I have commented this one out???

Maybe I should set the path but specify the depth??
for example `ini_set('session.cookie_path', 'http://domain1.com/*')`?

Comment: Try to set path as '/' statically for both addresses and please check if both cookies are served with/without "www". In other words "www.domain.com" is not equal to "domain.com" nor ".domain.com".

Comment: Also... make use of [EditThisCookie](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg?hl=pl) Chrome plugin, to check if both cookies are identical.